# Javascript: How to disable submit button until all fields are validated?

Tags: javascript, function, button, submit, disabled-control

I have several validation functions that work fine and I want to write an additional validation in simple javascript (**no jQuery, etc**) for the entire form that disables/enables the Submit button depending on whether the other validation functions return true or false.  How do I go about that?

For example, for my main HTML I have:

```
 <form id="form" method="POST">
      <label class="form">Field 1</label><input type="text" name="input1" onkeyup="validateInput1(); return false">
      <label class="form">Field 2</label><input type="text" name="input2" onkeyup="validateInput2(); return false">
      ...
      <button id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

For my script I have:

```
 function validateInput1(){
 ...
 }

 function validateInput2(){
 ...
 }
```

Now I want to write a function with something like:

```
function validateForm(){

    var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
    submitButton.disabled = true;

    /*If all other validation functions like validateInput1() returns true then submitButton.disabled = false*/
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Without jQuery, it's going to be a bit of the PITA. You'd have to loop through the input fields, and attach a change handler, then have it check the `validateForm()` function to see if all the forms are valid. After that, if they're all valid, set the submit button to enabled, otherwise set it to disabled.

Answer (score 5):

Start the button off as disabled. Hook to the `onchange` event for each of the form inputs, and then have it check the `validateForm()` function to see if all the forms are valid. After that, if they're all valid, set the submit button to enabled, otherwise set it to disabled.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#form input');

var validateInput1 = function()
{
  return document.getElementById('input1').value != '';
}

var validateInput2 = function()
{
  return document.getElementById('input2').value != '';
}
    
var validateForm = function() {

  if ( !validateInput1() ) {
    return false;
  }

  if ( !validateInput2() ) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

for ( var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++ )
{
  var checkValid = function() {
    document.getElementById('submit').disabled = !validateForm();
    
    //Is the same as:
    /*if ( !validateForm() )
    {
      document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled = false;
    }*/
  }
  
  inputs[i].addEventListener('change', checkValid);
  inputs[i].addEventListener('keyup', checkValid);
}
```

```html
<form id="form" method="POST" onsubmit="alert('Submitted!'); return false">
    <label class="form">Field 1</label><input type="text" name="input1" id="input1">
    <label class="form">Field 2</label><input type="text" name="input2" id="input2">
    <button id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: could you do a fiddle on this?  I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I'm having a hard time since what you coded is so different from my initial question.  I had the onkeyup="validateOption1(); return false" on mine but you took it out in your code and it's messing up my script.  Also, I don't have any return statements for my validation functions since I want them to be ambiguous functions.

Comment: Well then, you have to clarify exactly what you're looking for.