# How to disable submit input field until all required fields and checkboxes are empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a very simple web app, here is the link to the sandbox:

[codesandbox.io/s/eager-kalam-v1lpg](http://codesandbox.io/s/eager-kalam-v1lpg)

**The question is** how to disable submit input until all requested fields and checkbox are filled in? Sorry, I'm working with js only for a couple of days, so I'll appreciate any help

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296668/reactjs-form-input-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) attribute to your inputs. When one of the inputs in a form has this attribute but has not been filled at the moment the Submit button is clicked, the form will not be submitted. Instead, the [`invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/invalid_event) event will be fired on all inputs whose values are missing. You can use it to let the user know what needs to be filled in.

Here is a minimal example using React:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Input(props) {
  const [invalid, setInvalid] = useState(false);
  
  const handleInvalid = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Invalid');
    setInvalid(true);
  };
  
  const handleChange = () => setInvalid(false);
  
  const className = invalid ? 'invalid' : '';

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <input {...props} onInvalid={handleInvalid} onChange={handleChange} />
      {props.type === "checkbox" && (
        <label htmlFor={props.id}>
          {props.label}
        </label>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function Form() {
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Submit');
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Input name="name" placeholder="Name" required />
      <Input type="checkbox" name="accept" id="accept" label="I accept Terms of Usage" required />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.invalid input[type=text], .invalid input:not([type]) {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.invalid label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You can read more about client-side form validation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation). Spoiler: requiring a field is not the only thing you can do by just using HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could just start the element with the `disabled` attribute, and then check the validators as they update. Once they all hit the mark, you can remove the `disabled` attribute with

`document.querySelector('.button').removeAttr("disabled");`

Comment: Can you please give me a bit more detailed description? I'm working with react only for a couple of days and don't know how to check validators on update(

Answer (score 0):

you can add disabled attribute and check if the function returns true or not

e.g
disabled={!validateForm()}

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38810178/1916604

here is possible duplicate answer